# Lightning Wait Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there a lightning component that loops or waits for a record to be updated? I want to make a lightning component that is checking to see if this record has a field populated after a API call that is called from another process.

The flow I want to do, lightning component loads, checks field, waits checks again, then once populated does something else. I found this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:waiting/documentation) but it shows that it's depreciated and I don't understand it enough to know what to search for next.

Is there a keyword or concept to search about this?

Comment: Is promises the right way to go?

Comment: depending on your specific use case you may be able to use `force:recordData` and its `recordUpdated` mechanism to detect that the underlying record had been modified, check your field and then 'do something else' [Relevant Documentation about force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use Change Data Capture to wait for Record Updates.

Salesforce Guide on CDC
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/

LWC component to work with Streaming API ( CDC too)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation

use `/data/SObject__ChangeEvent` to subscribe to it

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the API yourself, use a Promise. If you're waiting on an external system to update, use the [lightning-emp-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) module to subscribe to changes via [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm).